# How to merge and sum dictionary values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'd like to sum up all values in multiple Python dictionaries with the same key and keep the other values as is if they have a different key.
The input dictionaries would look something like this:

```
dict1 = {'A':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':0}, 'B':{'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':0}}
dict2 = {'A':{'a':3, 'c':1, 'd':5}, 'B':{'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}, 'C':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1}}
```

Output:

```
dict3 = {'A':{'a':4, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':5}, 'B':{'a':5, 'b':0, 'c':1}, 'C':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1}}
```

Is there any way to achieve this result using only the standard library? This should also work with more than 2 dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very structure dependent, however something like ...

```
dicts = [
    {'A':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':0}, 'B':{'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':0}},
    {'A':{'a':3, 'c':1, 'd':5}, 'B':{'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}, 'C':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1}}
]

odict = {}
for d in dicts:
    for dk in d.keys():
        if dk not in odict:
            odict[dk] = {}
        for inner_dk in d[dk].keys():
            if inner_dk not in odict[dk]:
                odict[dk][inner_dk] = d[dk][inner_dk]
            else:
                odict[dk][inner_dk] += d[dk][inner_dk]

print(odict)
```

Answer (score 1):

A function that accepts multiple dicts:

```py
dict1 = {"A": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 0}, "B": {"a": 3, "b": 0, "c": 0}}
dict2 = {
    "A": {"a": 3, "c": 1, "d": 5},
    "B": {"a": 2, "b": 0, "c": 1},
    "C": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 1},
}


def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    if not dicts:
        return

    out = {}
    all_keys = set(dicts[0]).union(k for d in dicts[1:] for k in d)

    for k in all_keys:
        out[k] = {}
        for kk in set(dicts[0].get(k, {})).union(
            k_ for d in dicts[1:] for k_ in d.get(k, {})
        ):
            out[k][kk] = sum(d.get(k, {}).get(kk, 0) for d in dicts)

    return out


print(merge_dicts(dict1, dict2))
```

Prints:

```py
{'C': {'c': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'A': {'c': 1, 'd': 5, 'a': 4, 'b': 2}, 'B': {'c': 1, 'a': 5, 'b': 0}}
```

---

For input:

```py
dict1 = {"A": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 0}, "B": {"a": 3, "b": 0, "c": 0}}
dict2 = {
    "A": {"a": 3, "c": 1, "d": 5},
    "B": {"a": 2, "b": 0, "c": 1},
    "C": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 1},
}
dict3 = {
    "A": {"a": 100},
}


print(merge_dicts(dict1, dict2, dict3))
```

Prints:

```py
{'A': {'a': 104, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 5}, 'B': {'a': 5, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, 'C': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}}
```